Injection of sheaves and pullbacks
Let $X,Y$ be smooth complex projective varieties, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism. Let $F$ be a vector bundle of rank $k$ on $Y$, and let $E$ be a coherent subsheaf of $F$.
Consider the pullbacks: $f^*F$ is a vector bundle of rank $k$ on $X$, and $f^*E$ is still a coherent sheaf.
Question: does it still holds that we have an injection of sheaves $f^*E\hookrightarrow f^*F$?
My -very bad, because I have never learnt properly algebraic geometry- guess would be yes. An injection of sheaves correspond to a nonzero section $s$ of $H^0(Y,F\otimes E^\vee)$, and its pullback would give a section $f^*s: \mathcal{O}_X\to f^*(F\otimes E^\vee)$. Since $f^*(F\otimes E^\vee)=f^* F\otimes f^* E^\vee$, tensoring the above sheaf homorphism would give as a nonzero section $f^*s: f^*E\to f^*F$.
How far (and wrong) is my reasoning away from the correct idea?

This is wrong in general (unless $f$ is flat), because $f^*$ is not left exact.
For a simple counterexample let $Y = \mathbb{P}^1$, $F = \mathcal{O}_Y$, $E = \mathcal{O}(-1)$ and let the embedding $E \hookrightarrow F$ be given by a homogeneous coordinate $x_0$. Let further $f \colon X \to Y$ be the embedding of the point $x_0 = 0$. Then $f^*E \cong f^*F \cong \mathcal{O}_X$, but the morphism $f^*E \to f^*F$ is zero.
